# Data mapper not working (uninitialized constant)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sinatra, ruby-datamapper

I'm playing around with Sinatra and following a simple tutorial I found online ( http://carlosgabaldon.com/articles/singing-with-sinatra/).

The thing is though, every time I try to enter `DataMapper::Database.setup({...`

I get `uninitialized constant DataMapper::Database (NameError)`.. Any ideas why?

Comment: make sure you have all the gems necessary. Do you have a db running? Have you required all the gems? It's usually one of these things that lead to problems. Also make sure you have the proper db adapter.

Comment: Heres my full code..


require 'rubygems'
require 'sinatra'
require 'data_mapper'
DataMapper::Database.setup({
  :adapter  => 'sqlite3',
  :host     => 'localhost',
  :username => '',
  :password => '',
  :database => 'db/my_way_development'
})

Comment: That article is nearly three years old (March 2009) and the current DataMapper api is very different. You'd be best finding a more up to date tutorial.

Answer (score 4):

I had that same issue doing the tutorial on Sinatra/DataMapper on RubySource.

The problem was that I wan't calling

```
require 'dm-sqlite-adapter'
```

Answer (score 1):

Like others said, you should definitely use some newer/better tutorials. The [Getting Started](http://datamapper.org/getting-started.html) page on DataMapper's website is a good starting point, along with the rest of their [docs](http://datamapper.org/docs/).

To answer your question, this should connect to your database:

```
DataMapper.setup(:default, 'sqlite://db/my_way_development')
```